# How to compare object and List<> and object.value null when the value doesn't exist in list

Tags: c#, list, class, object, compare

I need to compare between my object and a list.
List contains attribute "nom_colonne", it fill by a query and the result is a list of attributes (same like my object AppareilsReparations)

For example :
if droit_utilisateur.nom_colonne = "Num_dossier" 
so i keep the value in arp.num_dossier

But if i don't have this value of my list droit_utilisateur :
arp.num_dossier will be null.

I wanted to cast my object with System.Collections.IList but impossible to cast. I have an error.

```
public class AppareilsReparations


{

    public string Num_dossier { get; set; }
    //public string reference_aff { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid Uid { get; set; }
    public string ref_sav { get; set; }

    public CodeDefaut codedefaut { get; set; }
    public CodeSymptome codesymptome { get; set; }
}

public class Droits
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int utilisateur_id { get; set; }
    public string nom_table { get; set; }
    public string nom_colonne { get; set; }
}


AppareilsReparations arp = db.Query<AppareilsReparations>
                   ("select * from v_appareils_reparations where ref_sav_client =@ref_sav", new { ref_sav }).SingleOrDefault();

List<Droits> droit_utilisateur = GetDroits("admin");
            //var appareil = new List<AppareilsReparations>();

            IList appareil = (IList)arp;

            var result = droit_utilisateur.Where(x => !appareil.Contains(x.nom_colonne)).ToList();
```

Comment: Hi Deos, please show us your error and the line where it occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found my problem, i post my code for everybody :

```
List<Droits> droit_utilisateur = GetDroits(username);
            Type myType = e.GetType();
            IList<PropertyInfo> props = new List<PropertyInfo>(myType.GetProperties());

            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in e.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                object propValue = prop.Name;
                if (droit_utilisateur.Any(s => s.nom_colonne.Contains(prop.Name/*, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)*/) == false))
                {
                    prop.SetValue(e, Convert.ChangeType(null, prop.PropertyType), null);
                }
            }


                return e;
```

Answer (score 0):

That's cause `AppareilsReparations` is not a type of `IList` and thus your cast would always fail `IList appareil = (IList)arp;`. Probably you wanted to do like below; just comparing with `Num_dossier` field of `AppareilsReparations` type

```
var result = droit_utilisateur.Where(x => x.nom_colonne == arp.Num_dossier).ToList();
```

Comment: thx for explications but i don't need to compare the value of arp.Num_dossier.
I need to know for each name of attribut of arp (num_dossier) is in list droit_utilisateur